# i am not getting onchange event for input type="datetime-local" in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
HTML
<html>
<body>
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="dateappt_tech" id="dateappt_tech" onchange="handler(event)">
</body>
</html> 

SCRIPT file
<script>
function handler(e) {
        alert(e.target.value);
    }
</script>
```

I want onchange event for input datetime-local.
I am not getting how to do it.

Comment: Your question could be phrased better, but thanks for posting. I had a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using datetime-local which will fire the on change event once all the fields are filled including time.

```html
<html>
<body>
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="dateappt_tech" id="dateappt_tech" onchange="handler(event)">
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="dateappt_tech" id="dateappt_tech" onchange="handler(event)">
</body>
</html> 

SCRIPT file
<script>
function handler(e) {
        alert(e.target.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This works well to capture the values once a user closes the date select popup.  I use this to with a start and end date field, to set the min and max values for each. very useful.